# How to get the number of map markers per country - ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, api, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm working with the Citybik.es API (http://api.citybik.es/) to show data on a Leaflet map.

[image]

At the moment, the code is showing every item in the map, but after analysing I would like to organize the data a little bit allowing the user to drill down the information, **when clicking on a marker**. Something like this:

1. Display number of networks per country **(each marker represents a network, so to speak, each marker per country)**
2. Display number of stations per network

The response looks something like this:

[image]

Here's the JavaScript:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

// code for map marker icon
   var myIcon = L.icon({
       iconUrl: 'data:image/png;base64,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',
       iconSize: [25, 41],
       iconAnchor: [12.5, 41],
       popupAnchor: [0, -41]
    });

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        location: {
            lat: 51.505,
            lng: -0.09,
        },
        bikeData: [],
        haveUsersLocation: false,
        zoom: 3,
    }

//lifecycle method to get the bike information
componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks')
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => {
            const networkData = response.networks;
            this.setState({
                bikeData: networkData
            });
        })
}


render() {
    const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng]
    const bikeData = this.state.bikeData;
    return (
        <Map className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {
                bikeData && bikeData.map((data) => {
                    console.log(data)
                    return (
                        <Marker
                            icon={myIcon}
                            key={data.id}
                            position={[data.location.latitude, data.location.longitude]}>
                            <Popup>
                                Name: {data.name} <br />
                                Station Details: {[data.location.city, data.location.country]}
                            </Popup>
                        </Marker>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Map>
    )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that instead of having each marker represent an individual item, you want each marker to represent a cluster of items at first? If yes, what about something like this: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster or maybe this reference could help https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering

Comment: Yeah, something kinda like that, but maybe simpler. I want the total number of each marker (being each marker a network) per country. For example: US -> Number of Networks: 20; ES -> Number of Networks: 57; @tlm

Comment: Got it.  The clustering is easy to set up but for your use case (where you want to specifically start out in separate countries) you might have to figure out some different customizations.  Looks like there was a github issue opened with some asking a similar question that makes reference to a few other SO questions as well.

Comment: @tlm Do you have a link for this question?

Comment: sorry -- forgot the link: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/749

Comment: Thanks you very much! @tlm

Comment: No problem...I hope those links help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this to get the count

```
  const networkCountByCountry = new Map();

  response.networks.forEach(network => {
    const country = network.location.country
    const countryObject = networkCountByCountry.has(country) ?   networkCountByCountry.get(country) : {
        id: country,
        count: 0
    };
    countryObject.count = countryObject.count + 1
    networkCountByCountry.set(countryObject.id, countryObject)
  }) 

 const networkCountByCountryArray = [...networkCountByCountry.values()]
```

Then, you can use a click event to filter to the selected country list.

A more complete example:

```
import L from "leaflet";
import { Map as MapLeaf, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

// code for map marker icon
var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl:
    "data:image/png;base64,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",
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12.5, 41],
  popupAnchor: [0, -41]
});

class MapDisplay extends Component {
  state = {
    location: {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09
    },
    selectedCountry: null,
    bikeData: [],
    haveUsersLocation: false,
    zoom: 3
  };

  //lifecycle method to get the bike information
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks")
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        const networkData = response.networks;
        const networkCountByCountry = new Map();
        response.networks.forEach(network => {
          const country = network.location.country;
          const countryObject = networkCountByCountry.has(country)
            ? networkCountByCountry.get(country)
            : { id: country, count: 0, location: network.location };
          countryObject.count = countryObject.count + 1;
          networkCountByCountry.set(countryObject.id, countryObject);
        });
        const networkCountByCountryArray = [...networkCountByCountry.values()];
        this.setState({
          bikeData: networkData,
          bikeCountryData: networkCountByCountryArray
        });
      });
  }

  countryMarkerClick(country) {
    console.log(country);
    this.setState({ selectedCountry: country });
  }

  render() {
    const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng];
    if (this.state.selectedCountry) {
      const bikeData = this.state.bikeData.filter(
        network => network.location.country === this.state.selectedCountry
      );

      return (
        <MapLeaf className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {bikeData &&
            bikeData.map(data => {
              console.log(data);
              return (
                <Marker
                  icon={myIcon}
                  key={data.id}
                  position={[data.location.latitude, data.location.longitude]}
                >
                  <Popup>
                    Name: {data.name} <br />
                    Station Details:{" "}
                    {[data.location.city, data.location.country]}
                  </Popup>
                </Marker>
              );
            })}
        </MapLeaf>
      );
    }

    const bikeCountryData = this.state.bikeCountryData;
    return (
      <MapLeaf className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {bikeCountryData &&
          bikeCountryData.map(data => {
            return (
              <Marker
                icon={myIcon}
                key={data.id}
                position={[data.location.latitude, data.location.longitude]}
              >
                <Popup>
                  Name: {data.id} <br />
                  Stations: {[data.count]} <br />
                  <span onClick={this.countryMarkerClick.bind(this, data.id)}>
                    {" "}
                    -->{" "}
                  </span>
                </Popup>
              </Marker>
            );
          })}
      </MapLeaf>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a question: Why `import Map as MapLeaf`? @R. Wright

Comment: Oh, to distinguish between the JavaScript [native Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object and the Leaflet Map object.