# Filter react-table and react-leaflet marker at the same time using textfield (Show filter data in table and marker in the map)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-table

I am new to react-leaflet. Need little help to fix my issue. Follow up with [Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557802/how-to-get-the-number-of-map-markers-per-country-reactjs)

I have textfield which filter data. I was able to filter data in the table but not able to filter the data in the map. 
For example: if I search for name: 'VaiBike' it should show in table and marker in the map. Note: only show the data which is filter in map as well as in the table. so does for the other data.

How can I change my code so that I can show marker and data in table at the same time.

**Running code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
    import './style.css'
    import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
    import L from 'leaflet'
    import icon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'
    import iconShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'
    import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
    // Import React Table
    import ReactTable from 'react-table'
    import 'react-table/react-table.css'
    import matchSorter from 'match-sorter'

    var myIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl:
        'data:image/png;base64,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',
      iconSize: [25, 41],
      iconAnchor: [12.5, 41],
      popupAnchor: [0, -41],
    })
    let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: icon,
      shadowUrl: iconShadow,
    })

    L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon

    export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        location: {
          lat: 51.505,
          lng: -0.09,
          filterAll: '',
        },
        bikeData: [],
        haveUsersLocation: false,
        zoom: 3,
      }
      }
      //lifecycle method to get the bike information
      componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks')
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(response => {
            const networkData = response.networks
            this.setState({
              bikeData: networkData,
            })
          })
      }
      filterAll = e => {
        const { value } = e.target
        const filterAll = value
        const filtered = [{ id: 'all', value: filterAll }]
        const filterdMap =[{id:'bikeData', value: filterAll}]
        this.setState({ filterAll, filtered ,filterdMap})
      }

      render() {
        const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng]
        const bikeData = this.state.bikeData
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              height: '100vh',
            }}
            id="map"
          >
            <div align="right">
              <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField
                  id="row"
                  label="Search Bike"
                  margin="normal"
                  value={this.state.filterAll}
                  onChange={this.filterAll}
                />
              </form>
            </div>
            <Map className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
              <TileLayer
                attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              />
              {bikeData &&
                bikeData.map(data => {
                  console.log(data)
                  return (
                    <Marker
                      icon={myIcon}
                      key={data.id}
                      position={[data.location.latitude, data.location.longitude]}
                    >
                      <Popup>
                        Name: {data.name} <br />
                        Station Details:{' '}
                        {[data.location.city, data.location.country]}
                      </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                  )
                })}
            </Map>
            <div>
              <ReactTable
                filtered={this.state.filtered}
                defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
                  String(row[filter.id]) === filter.value
                }
                data={bikeData}
                columns={[
                  {
                    columns: [
                      {
                        Header: ' Name',
                        accessor: 'name',
                        filterAll: true,
                      },

                      {
                        Header: '',
                        id: 'all',
                        width: 0,
                        resizable: false,
                        sortable: false,
                        Filter: () => {},
                        getProps: () => {
                          return {}
                        },
                        filterMethod: (filter, rows) => {
                          const result = matchSorter(rows, filter.value, {
                            keys: ['name'],
                            threshold: matchSorter.rankings.WORD_STARTS_WITH,
                          })

                          return result
                        },
                        filterAll: true,
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ]}
                defaultPageSize={10}
              />
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Help with running code highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wowza that's a decent chunk of code. Can you paste a more minimal component -- ie one that contains *only* the bare minimum needed to replicate your problem? Dissecting your code in this way will often help you to spot and resolve the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll need to make a few adjustments to your code. First, add state to track the "filtered bike data" (ie the data that is visible to users in the UI). You can do so by adding something like this in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    location: {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      filterAll: '',
    },
    bikeData: [],
    filteredBikeData : [], // Add this
    haveUsersLocation: false,
    zoom: 3,
  }
  }
```

Now, in you `filterAll` all text field change handler, you'll want to update the `filteredBikeData` state based on the current field value. You can do so with something as follows:

```
filterAll = e => {
    const { value } = e.target

    // Get a filtered list of bikes based on original list
    const filteredBikes = this.state.bikeData.filter(bike => {

        // Filter bikes by name. Use toLowerCase to avoid case sensitivity issues
        return bike.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    })

    const filterAll = value
    const filtered = [{ id: 'all', value: filterAll }]
    const filterdMap =[{id:'bikeData', value: filterAll}]

    // Update state to include filtered bikes array
    this.setState({ filterAll, filtered ,filterdMap, filteredBikes})
}
```

Finally, you'll want to render markers based on the filtered array of bikes - update your render method like so:

```
{ /* use filteredBikes instead of bikes */
{ this.state.filteredBikes && this.state.filteredBikes.map(data => {
    console.log(data)
    return (
    <Marker
        icon={myIcon}
        key={data.id}
        position={[data.location.latitude, data.location.longitude]}
    >
        <Popup>
        Name: {data.name} <br />
        Station Details:{' '}
        {[data.location.city, data.location.country]}
        </Popup>
    </Marker>
    )
})}
```

As an extra, you might also want to default the value of `filteredBikes` to the response that you get from the server, so that the user initially sees something on screen:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks')
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        const networkData = response.networks
        this.setState({
          bikeData: networkData,
          filteredBikeData : networkData // Add this
        })
      })
  }
```

Comment: is it possible can i search by id and name at the same time. like can I add multiple return in filteredBikes?

Comment: Yes,  this is quite easy - is id a accessed via `bike.id`?

Comment: You could update this line like so:

`return (bike.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1) || ((bike.id + '').indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1)`

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770794/react-js-rechart-zoom-in-out-and-brush-issue) can you help with rechart issues please..